# Oracle Database Realtime Sync

Tags: database, oracle

Client is using Oracle Database Standard Edition so Active Data guard feature is not available and he wants to have a standby replica of the database which can take over the environment as soon as the main production database or server goes down. He also has Veeam backup and replication which he uses for taking backup.

What are the alternatives, please suggest.

Comment: What operating system and which version of Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In general, all HA options require the purchase of Enterprise Edition, or of some other product like GoldenGate. The one possible exception would be if your client is using the Standard Edition 2 (SE2) release, in which case you might be able to configure RAC One Node. This would use the same data files (so not really replication), but allow the instance processes to fail over to a second server if the first were to go down.

Note: Veeam is NOT a backup solution for Oracle. It only protects the server OS, or perhaps could make cold backups of the database. You MUST use RMAN if you expect to be able to recover the database to a specific point in time in the event of a failure or file corruption.